# What type of noun or word is used used for a juvenile animal?

Tags: nouns

For example 'collective noun'. 'Flock' of geese.

Is there a term for words like kitten, cub, spiderling or lamb.

Something like ' juvenile noun'.

Comment: It's unlikely that there will be a specific term for {nouns referencing juvenile animals}, any more than for {nouns referencing hardback books}, {nouns referencing womens cricket teams}, {nouns referencing large islands} or {nouns referencing fast cars}.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth Fast car? ***Speedster***, _"And the two speedsters are presently parked at Sundaram Motors on Mount Road."_ [ODO](https://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/speedster)

Comment: @NVZ We're not looking for a single-word term for 'fast car'; we're looking for an existing term to describe 'that set of nouns referring to fast cars/speedsters'. etc in my analogies. 'Clarkson nouns' doesn't exist.  OP requires 'What is a term for the set of all nouns, such as kitten, cub, ... , which identify young animals?'

Comment: [Wikipedia](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/Appendix:Animals), which loves to use fancy terms, makes do with 'Terms for the young of the animal'.

Comment: Maybe *zoodiminutive*?

Comment: Questions which lack results of research are out of scope.
Requests to help name something are out of scope.
Word or phrase requests are out of scope, unless they are expert-level, particularly interesting, unique, and thought-provoking, and show effort and research.
For an introduction to the site, take the [Tour]. For help writing a good question, see [ask].

Comment: There is in certain cases. A diminutive form referring to an animal almost always refers to a young animal: _gosling, duckling, suckling_. In languages with productive diminutives (like Lushootseed, which has several types of root reduplication), you get the reference elsewhere -- with the root _yub-il_ 'to starve (of human) / to die (of animal)', for instance, there is _ʔuyuyub-il_ 'a small animal died' (CV- reduplication, diminutive), _ʔuyubyub-il_ 'people starved everywhere (CVC- reduplication, augmentative), _ʔuyubub-il_ 'he's run-down' (-VC reduplication, distributive).

Answer (score -2):

In the generic case of "juvenile noun," ***young*** may be most appropriate. However, juveniles, juvenals, hatchlings, fledglings, immatures, kittens, cubs, pups, chicks, etc. are usually used as more focused terms for stages of immature animals. Technically, discipline-specific terminology is best unless referring to all animals, in which case immatures or subadults or (suboptimal) juveniles would be warranted.

Comment: This does not answer the question. Which is 'What is a term to cover the nouns of the set {'juveniles', 'juvenals', 'hatchlings', 'fledglings', 'immatures', 'kittens', 'cubs', 'pups', 'chicks' ...}?' A 'no' is better given as a comment.

Comment: Do not answer questions which should be closed.
For an introduction to the site, take the [Tour]. For help writing a good answer, see [answer].

Comment: Thank you both for the critique. I read the 'flock' equivalent as the goal, and *young* is the best option in AmE (and science). I've edited to put that at the front but retain the rest as a guide to aim people toward better uses in specific cases.

Comment: @Edwin Ashworth and @ MετάEd please enlighten me about why an answer I am professionally well qualified to provide (*young* is a collective noun for any number of more specific words for immature animals) is somehow negatively viewed on ELU? There seems to be some lapsus in communication, and it may very well be mine.

Comment: 'Young' is the collective noun for puppies, kittens, chicks, elvers.... OP wants a term to describe the **words** 'puppies', 'kittens' etc like 'proper nouns' describes the **words** 'Blackpool', 'Tom', 'Russia', 'Hamlet', 'Dyson', 'Kidnapped'.... The word 'kitten' isn't a 'young' any more than the word 'Blackpool' is a 'proper'. And 'young noun' isn't used.